# Clarifying the notion of basic/free variables in a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I have a fundamental confusion with regards to the notion of free/basic variables.

Consider the following linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & -4 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This system has augmented matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 4 \\
2 & -4 & 0  & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which row reduces to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & -8 & 2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The last matrix is in echelon form. Columns 1 and 2 are pivot columns, so $x_1,x_2$ are basic variables. The third column is not a
pivot column, so $x_3$ is a free variable.   Finally, the last column is not a pivot column, so the system is consistent.

---

The above analysis tells me that $x_3$ is a free variable. I interpret this as saying "$x_1,x_2$ can be expressed as a function of $x_3$, while $x_3$ can be set equal to any number". For example, I can set $x_3=200$. In turn,
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+2x_2-200=4 \\
2x_1-4x_2=5
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x_2=\frac{403}{8}, x_1=\frac{413}{4}
$$

Nevertheless, just by doing naive computations, I realised that we could also "express $x_1$, $x_3$ as a function of $x_2$, while setting $x_2$ equal to any number". For example, I can set $x_2=7$. In turn,
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+14-x_3=4\\
2x_1-28=5
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x_1=\frac{33}{2}, x_3=\frac{53}{2}
$$
Alternatively, we could also "express $x_2$, $x_3$ as a function of $x_1$, while setting $x_1$ equal to any number". For example, I can set $x_1=0$. In turn,
$$
\begin{cases}
2x_2-x_3=4\\
-4x_2=5
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x_2=-\frac{13}{2}, x_3=-\frac{5}{4}
$$

---

Hence, **my question**: what is the relation between

- the fact that $x_3$ is a free variable and $x_1,x_2$ are basic variables (from the row-reduced matrix)
- and the fact that in the system above I am free to fix the value of anyone among $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and I will always be able to solve for the other two unrestricted variables

Comment: Note that the order of the columns is arbitrary in a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got three column vectors, and any pair of them are independent and thus span $\Bbb R^2$. The solution set is one-dimensional (affine) (aka a line) so of the form $v+tw$, where $v,w$ are some vectors  and $t$ is a free real variable. We can choose this to be $x_3$, or any of the other variables if you prefer.

You can then transform the equations to $$\begin{align}x_1+2x_2 &= 4+x_3\\
x_1 - 4x_2 &= 5\end{align}$$

and solve these in terms of $x_3$ uniquely. We get (add twice the first equation to the second and we get $3x_1 = 13+2x_3$ so $x_1 = \frac{1}{3}(13+2x_3)$, and subtraction the equations: $6x_2 = x_3-1$ and hence $x_2 = \frac{1}{6}(x_3 - 1)$ (we could also do another elimination step on this new system) so we can write the solution line as

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{13}{3}\\ -\frac16\end{pmatrix} + x_3  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3}\\ \frac16\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. (1) Can we say that in this specific case "$x_3$ is a free variable, $x_1,x_2$ are basic variables" or, equivalently, "$x_1$ is a free variable, $x_3,x_2$ are basic variables" or, equivalently, "$x_2$ is a free variable, $x_1,x_3$ are basic variables"? (2) Is there any way to realise from the echelon form that we are "free" to permute the columns? This somehow relates to my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012647/when-are-we-free-in-setting-the-free-variables if you can help.

Comment: @TEX They can all be free, that's the point. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is: is there a formal way to understand from the echelon form (or any other form) when any variable can be set as the free variable? This is not always the case.

Comment: @TEX you just use $x_3$ and get the full solution set. Why do more?

Comment: Because this relates to a more general result that I need to prove. I want to understand when I'm free to set the free variables and how I can detect that.

Comment: @TEX reorder thr columns to a diagonal form. The rest is free. Quite easy. These variables we can choose freely are not uniquely determined.

Comment: Thanks. can you help to understand what it means "reorder the columns to a diagonal form"?

Comment: @TEX so that the nonzero pivots are on the diagonal.